# Restrict group member to send stickers for a while

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to restrict some members from sending stickers for a while. I'm using `restrict_chat_member()`, but it gives me error: *Bad Request: method is available only for supergroups*
*I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI*

I'm also tried `promote_chat_member()`, but it doesn't have attribute "can_send_other_messages".